# TS: Declare object as a type while keeping the keys

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I would like to type our Material UI styles and classes. For that I have the following construction:

```
import { StyleRulesCallback, StyleRules } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export type StyleType = StyleRulesCallback<string> | StyleRules<string>;

export type ClassesType<S extends StyleType> =
  S extends StyleRulesCallback<string>
    ? { [K in keyof ReturnType<S>]: string }
    : { [K in keyof S]: string };
```

Now, when I have some styles like

```
const styles: StyleType = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
};
```

and I type them as `StyleType` and the classes as `ClassesType<typeof styles>`, the inferred type of classes is `{[x: string]: string}`. However, I would like to keep the keys, i.e. that classes is of type `{root: string}` which works when I remove the typing of the styles.

Is there a way of typing the styles as StyleType (or similar) while still keeping the keys?

Comment: I don't have typing from @material-ui in scope so I can't demo this directly.  Taking the answer from the other question and adapting yields something like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wRRzXw), but it would be nice if you could give a standalone [mre] to be sure.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey @jcalz That exactly solves my problem! Thank you :)